# ScrollView not work

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[what my screen looks like now click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydsl2.png)

I can not scroll horizontally due to some reasons, but I cannot figure out the problem, I have already set flex for the style and my code show as following:

```
<View style={styles.contentContainer}>
      <ScrollView horizontal>
        {meetups.map((meetup, i) => (
          <View key={i} style={styles.meetupCard}>
            <View style={styles.meetupCardTopContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.meetupCardTitle}>
                {meetup.title}
              </Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.meetupCardBottomContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.meetupCardMetaName}>
                {meetup.group.name}
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.meetupCardMetaDate}>
                Mar 2m 6:00pm
              </Text>
            </View>

          </View>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
```

and the styles define as following:

```
const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    flex: 1
  },
  titleContainer: {
    flex: 0.1,
    paddingHorizontal: '2.5%',
    paddingVertical: '2.5%'
  },
  title: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 25,
    fontFamily: 'SignikaRegular'
  },
  contentContainer: {
    flex:1
  },
  meetupCard: {
    height: 200,
    width: 175,
    marginHorizontal: '1.5%',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor:'#fff',
    backgroundColor: '#40D4EB'
  },
  meetupCardTopContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'relative'
  },
  meetupCardBottomContainer: {
    flex: 0.5,
  },
  meetupCardMetaDate: {
    fontSize: 13,
    fontFamily: 'SignikaLight'
  }
});
```

How I can make it scroll sucessfully?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It will scrollable when remove **marginHorizontal** out from **meetupCard** or not use percentage